# Bug Ionic/Angular (Nested) Router issue, next Component not loading and not being displayed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-router

Bug

**Ionic version:**
[x] **4.x**

**Current behavior:**
In our Ionic/Angular Application we are seeing a quite strange behavior and are not able to solve it.
When we navigate in our app to e.g. this route:
`http://localhost:8100/tabs/projects/5d3b0763537555635c7f9e12`
and wether if we route in our html like
`[routerLink]="['add-report']"`
or in the component over
`this.router.navigate(['./add-report'], { relativeTo: this.route});`

Then it adds 'add-report' to the route, so the route looks like this:
`http://localhost:8100/tabs/projects/5d3b0763537555635c7f9e12/add-report`

But the component is not loaded and not displayed.

**Expected behavior:**
The component should be loaded and displayed if the route changes.

**Steps to reproduce:**

In our Ionic/Angular Application we are seeing a quite strange behavior and are not able to solve it.
When we navigate in our app to e.g. this route:
`http://localhost:8100/tabs/projects/5d3b0763537555635c7f9e12`
and wether if we route in our html like
`[routerLink]="['add-report']"`
or in the component over
`this.router.navigate(['./add-report'], { relativeTo: this.route});`

Then it adds 'add-report' to the route, so the route looks like this:
`http://localhost:8100/tabs/projects/5d3b0763537555635c7f9e12/add-report`

But the component is not loaded and not displayed.

Either if we use the routing like:

`{
    path: ':projectId',
    component: ProjectOverviewComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'add-report',
        component: AddReportComponent
      }
    ]`

with a `<router-outlet>` 
or the router-module, it is not working.

If you need more information please ask.

Comment: Did you tried opening it without 'tabs'? Depending on how the tabs routing was written you can experience different behaviours... Also did you check in your ProjectOverviewComponent the value of :projectId ? I suspect it could take it as '5d3b0763537555635c7f9e12/add-report'...

Comment: Hi @Monomachus thanks for your answer.
I will copy the tabs routing for you in an hour, so you can check. But I think it is right.
How can I check, if it takes the route as '5d3b0763537555635c7f9e12/add-report'?

Comment: You can get the value of the :projectId from Angular route snapshot. https://medium.com/@tiboprea/accessing-url-parameters-in-angular-snapshot-vs-subscription-efc4e70f9053

Comment: Hi @Monomachus,
yeah I know and i tried. The projectId is the '5d3b0763537555635c7f9e12'.
The add-report behind it, I can see in the browser url and I added a console.log statement in the component. It shows in the chrome dev tools (logging out: "add-report"). But the view is not changing

Comment: Can you put the code somewhere, like a zip so I could take a look?